# Cómo trasladar comentarios de Tablas y Columnas en ERWin al Script que se genera con Forward Engineer?

Tags: sql

Intento modelar una BD en **ERWin** y trasladarla a SQL, con **comentarios** para Tablas y Columnas.

En ERWin, especifico los comentarios para columnas en **Columns.Comment** y para tablas en **Tables.Comment**, pero al generar el Script en **Tools.Forward Engineer.Schema Generation.Preview**, no se me generan las instrucciones para trasladar esos comentarios a base de datos.

En las opciones del generador estoy chequeando **Other Options.Comments**, pero nada.